# Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce 'img' tags as an image

Tags: html, reactjs, image, accessibility, alt

I have a React application and I'm getting the following error:

`Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce 'img' tags as an image. You don’t need to use the words 'image', 'photo,' or 'picture' (or any specified custom words) in the alt prop  jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt`

I'm using the `alt` tag on my images and including these keywords in my alt text but the error still persists. What should I do now?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :) My guess here is a simple misinterpretation of the rule and error message. The rule is requiring you to _remove_ those words from the `alt` tag rather than _include_ them. For example, if the `alt` contains "image" you must remove the word "image". I added a short answer below that hopefully helps explain.

Comment: Either you change the alt text (which goes in an **attribute**, not a tag) so it doesn't use one of those words, or you disable that rule. We can't tell you what you should do because we don't know what the image looks like, what context you've used it in, or what alt text you've written so we've no way of knowing if that alt text you've written is actually appropriate. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. https://web.archive.org/web/20180311182502/http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html is probably worth a read too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to an error generated by [react-a11y](https://github.com/reactjs/react-a11y/) and specifically the [img-redundant-alt](https://github.com/reactjs/react-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/img-redundant-alt.md) rule.

The `img-redundant-alt` rule has the following default options: `["image","picture","photo"]`

This means one of your `alt` descriptions contains one of these words. The logic behind the error is that describing an image as *image* is not useful to readers.

You can resolve by *removing* any instances of the words "image", "picture", or "photo" from your `alt` tags or by modifying the default options for this rule if you wish to ignore them.

Comment: How is this applied in practice? I don't know in advance when writing the `alt` attribute what image will be shown here... it can be a user's profile picture for example. So I can't describe the contents any better than as "profile picture", no?